# How to Select Multiple Item from a foreign key field in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a form where I want to display multiple select foreign key field. I want some thing like that [image: pic]

here's my Model

I want Developer_assigned field as like that pic. I want to select multiple developer at time.
can someone help me with the solution?

Comment: You want a [Many-to-many relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) not a many to one relationship (which is what a `ForeignKey` is used for)

Comment: Hi @Abdul, I have tried with many-to-many retation. but getting some error i.e. <class 'hello.admin.Jira_StoriesAdmin'>: (admin.E109) The value of 'list_display[7]' must not be a ManyToManyField.
can you help me to fix that ?

Comment: there's no field named list_display. actually list_display[7] id nothing but my Developer_Assigned field

Comment: In your model admin you have an attribute `list_display` being a list. Remove `Developer_Assigned` from this list (A m2m being in list display won't look good, and may take up too much space) is what the error is telling you to do...

Comment: Thanks @Abdul, i resolved that problem but in my UI table now names are not showing . it is showing hello.developer.None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/widgets/

There will be a Select2Multiple/ MultipleChoiceField. That will do the job.

So for you on a foreign key. Keep like that and in forms.py add the SelectMultiple widget to this field and your good to go.

Here is the example:

Forms: sub_glass will be your foreignkey field. If you use modelform for example you can use this behind your field.

```
Item, fields=("sub_glass"),
    widgets={'sub_glass': SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control-sm form-control js-multiple-select', 'multiple':'multiple'})},
```

Comment: Hey @Bastu, I'm not able to understand where to add SelectMultiple widget. I have updated my question with form code . can you please guide me?

Comment: I eddited answer @RikaDas . If you need better explanation let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Change your developer assigned fk to use ManyToMany field instead.